# How to increment numbers when using multicursor in android studio

Tags: android-studio

I want to write numbers when i use multi cursor like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275171/is-there-a-way-to-increment-numbers-when-using-multiple-cursors-in-atom) in android studio

Answer (score 1):

You can use `String Manipulation` plugin to do that.

[image]

After installing this plugin follow this steps:

```
1 - >
```

[image]

```
2 - >
```

[image]

```
3 - >
```

[image]